# LINQ to SQL and Attaching Child Objects

Tags: sql, linq

I am writing a class that will (hopefully) allow manipulation of data through a LINQ to SQL layer without having to know what individual objects you are working with.  So far, it works fine for cascading selects and inserts, but I am having a hard time with updates.

Here is the save method I am using:

```
if ((long)entity.GetType().GetProperty(GetPrimaryKeyName(entity)).GetValue(entity, null) == 0)
            {
                Context.GetTable(entity.GetType()).InsertOnSubmit(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                Context.GetTable(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity, true);
            }

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntitySet<>))
                {
                    IEnumerable children = (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(entity, null);
                    foreach (object child in children)
                    {
                        Save(child);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This works until I have a child object as part of an update.  For example, if I pass in a Customer object with an Address child object that needs to be updated and not inserted, as soon as I Attach the Customer object I now have TWO Address objects in my EntitySet - the one pulled up from the database, and the new one.  I then get an exception "Cannot attach an entity that already exists" when it attempts to attach the first Address child object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Could you possibly attach the child entities before you attach the parent entity? Would that prevent the attach issue?

Just use reflection to get all of the `EntityRef` objects, and attach the `Entity` property of each to the appropriate table.

Comment: I ended up doing just that, and you are correct.  Attaching from the "bottom up" solved the problem.